# Different constants in android projects that have same code base(library project)

Tags: android

I have an android library project.
Two projects-A and B are using that library project code.

I have this code in the shared android library project
RequestAdFromAdmob(constantAdId)

I wish to use a different ad id for project A and project B, so what is the best practice to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just want to make a parameter that is passed into the library?

Comment: I assume `RequestAdFromAdmob(constantAdId)` is called inside your shared library and `constantAdId` is stored there. Otherwise, the problem is not clear (for me)

Answer (score 0):

Pass the hashed name of your class/project to the library